# Losing Contents of NSArray after ViewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on my first iOS application: a cookbook that stores an array of Recipe objects. The array is declared like so in the header file like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *recipeArray;
```

In the viewDidLoad method I fill the array with recipes from the XML file like so:

```
self.recipeArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:arrayFromXML];
```

Within the viewDidLoad method, after that line of code I am able to successfully access the contents of the array.

The problem is when I want to access the array in the prepareForSegue method, the array seems to be empty. Right at the beginning of the prepareForSegue method I put in the test output statement:

```
NSLog(@"Name called from segue: %@", [self.recipeArray[0] name]);
```

and it prints out "Name called from segue: (null)

Why does this happen? How can I get the contents of the array and how come they aren't saved after the viewDidLoad method finishes executing?

Comment: If the array was empty, you'd get a crash. The array seems to have been removed (nilled). Where else in the code are you changing `recipeArray` ?

Comment: @TBlue, so and why should that changes anything?

Comment: this is the only place in code that I am changing recipeArray. There are other places in code where I access it, like in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method like so:


`code`cell.textLabel.text = [self.recipeArray[indexPath.row] name];
    [cell setRecipeForCell:self.recipeArray[indexPath.row]];
    NSLog(@"Recipe For Cell set as: %@", [self.recipeArray[indexPath.row] name]);
    return cell;
`code`
and strangely enough, that works fine

Comment: How many instances of the view controller do you have? Is one getting the array and a different one getting the segue?

Comment: @Wain yes. There is the RecipeTableViewController which contains the array and the table of all the recipes and there is the RecipeViewController which is the detailed view that receives the specific recipe.

Comment: Here is all the code in my prepareForSegue method:

`NSLog(@"Name called from segue: %@", [self.recipeArray[0] name]);
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Recipe"]){
        NSLog(@"if statement called");
        int indexTapped = [[self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender] row];
        
        RecipeViewController *cont = (RecipeViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        
        NSLog(@"Name: %@", [self.recipeArray[indexTapped] name]);
        
        cont.recipe = self.recipeArray[indexTapped];
        }
}`

Comment: But, where are you instantiating RecipeTableViewController? Code / storyboard / both? And where are you triggering the segue?

Comment: RecipeTableViewController is being made in storyboard. prepareForSegue is written the RecipeTableViewController class and is set up in the storyboard. Could this have something to do with the fact that loadFromXML returns a mutableArray??

Comment: The problem seems to be fixed when I call `self.recipeArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[self loadFromXML]];` again in the prepareForSegue method, but I don't think that's a good solution, is it?

Comment: so `loadFromXML` is a method and not a variable?

Comment: correct. it is a method that returns an NSMutableArray

Comment: What happens when you try to access the array from anywhere other than viewDidLoad or prepareForSegue? And are you setting your original data source to nil somewhere in the view controller?

Comment: you have in m file "@synthesize recipeArray;"? if don't… try to use only _recipeArray in all "sentence" instead of self.recipeArray. Give it a try…

Comment: @TonyMkenu: that doesnt make much sense. a property doesnt need to be synthesized explicitly anymore.

Comment: Just try... 2 days ago I had the same behavior :)

Comment: @TonyMkenu This did not make any difference

Comment: hi can y upload code which u use in viewdidload

Answer (score 0):

A very common beginner mistake is to have multiple instances of an object, typically a view controller. This can happen if you instantiate your view controller programmatically but the controller is also specified in a .xib or storyboard file. For example, if you've hooked up a segue between two view controllers in your storyboard, but you're also doing something like:

```
MyViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
vc.dataFileName = @"TheDataFile.txt";
```

then multiple copies of the controller is very likely your problem. You've got the one that you instantiate and provide a data file to as above, and one that the storyboard creates when the user taps a button or otherwise activates the segue.

Try putting a breakpoint in your `-viewDidLoad` method and see whether the value of `self` (that's the address of the view controller in this case) is the same every time you hit it.

If your problem is, in fact, due to multiple copies of your view controller, you'll probably wonder how you're supposed to set up the view controller if you don't instantiate it. The answer, of course, is that that's exactly what `-prepareForSegue:` is for. That's where you can tell the new view controller what file to get its data from, or otherwise set up the view controller so that it can do its job.

Comment: I am not doing any instantiating of the RecipeTableViewController besides what's being done in the storyboard

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to make a mutable copy of you NSArray like this

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:arrayFromXML];

self.recipeArray = [array mutableCopy];
```

Then try to use this recipeArray in your prepareForSegue method. I think you will get content of array as in viewDidLoad.

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Why do you think that will help? The property isn't defined as mutable.

Comment: This did not fix the problem. The contents of the array during the prepareForSegue method are still null.

Comment: If this was the right solution, it would be easier to simply do: `self.recipeArray = [arrayFromXML mutableCopy];`. No need for the wasted intermediate array.

Comment: where you called performSegueWithIdentifier method?